# Undefined value error in PHP (a beginner's guide) example script

Tags: php

Hoping someone can help me identify how to to initialize this variable ($value) from this example script I have copied from PHP A beginner's guide book by Vikram Vaswani.

I have turned on the display_erors value in php.ini and it is returning this error in the browser.

Notice: Undefined variable: cities in C:\BitNami\wordpress-3.6-0\apache2\htdocs\associative-array.php on line 23

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\BitNami\wordpress-3.6-0\apache2\htdocs\associative-array.php on line 23

Here's is my code as copied from page 94 of this book

```
<?php

// define array

$citites = array(

"United Kingdom" => "London",

"United States" => "Washington DC",

"France" => "Paris",

"India" => "Delhi" 

);

// Iterate over the associative array
// and print each value
// this example as supplied in the book
// returns uninitialized error for either $key or $value on line 20


foreach ($cities as $key => $value) {

 echo "$value is in $key. \r\n";

  }

?>
```

Also in the same chapter this other example as copied, for "array iterator" just hangs indefinitely in the browser. UP till this all the examples from the book seemed to be working perfectly.

This is the code as copied from the book for the array iterator example. Anyone know why this hangs indefinitely and doers not display output to the browser. Thanks very much for the help.

```
<?php

// define associative array (hash)

$cities = array(

"United States" => "Washington",

"United Kingdom" => "London",

"France" => "Paris",

"Spain" => "Madrid",

"Italy" => "Rome"

);

// Create an array itterator object

$iterator = new ArrayIterator($cities);

// rewind to beginning of array

$iterator->rewind();

// iterate over the array
// print each value

while ($iterator->valid()) {

    print $iterator->current() . " is in " . $iterator->key() . ". \r\n";

$iterator->next;

 }

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `$iterator->next` to `$iterator->next()` near the last line.

`$iterator->next` doesn't work because PHP assumes you are accessing a field rather than calling a method. Calling a method requires the brackets `()`.

Comment: SHiNKiROU! thanks for the help with the second code block array iterator example, I tried your advice and it now works :) Now I'm just looking for the first code block problem?

Comment: You spelled the first variable name wrong: It should `$cities` instead of `$citites`

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that by `$iterator->next`, you mean to be calling a function rather than attempting to access the variable of the class `ArrayIterator` (`$iterator`), named `next`.

In order to call a function, you need to append a set of brackets after the function name i.e. `function_name()`, with or without a series of parameters if neccessary.

Thus, instead of `$iterator->next`, you should use `$iterator->next()`.

Answer (score 1):

On the first example, the error is in this line:

```
$citites = array(
```

You misspelled "cities" here, and that's breaking the foreach loop.

On the second example, just change `$iterator->next` to `$iterator->next()`. That will tell PHP that it's a method rather than a field, allowing it to be called correctly.

Comment: Ahh! thanks Gabriel. Also thanks to Max and Shinkiru, you guys rock! I can finally on to the next examples.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a method,so you should close it with first brackets.you should use $iterator->next() instead of $iterator->next.